# How to get uniq obj from NSMutableDictionary key

Tags: objective-c

All.
I have a NSMutableArray , which name is dummyPerson. And it's element is NSMutableDictionary. Like this following code. I want to exclude duplicated screenName.

```

```
self.dummyPeople = [{screenName: "apple",tweet: "hi"},{screenName:"orange",tweet:"foo"},{screenName:"apple",tweet: "hoge"}];
// filteredByScreenName is procedure code.

[self.dummyPeople filteredByScreenName]

#=>  return [{screenName:"apple",tweet:"hi"},{screenName:"orange",tweet:"foo"}];
```

```

Do you have any Idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use a NSMutableDictionary to map from screenName to tweet?

Comment: Thanks to comment this post.Yes, I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not going to write code for you, but here is what I would do:

Create a temporary array to hold found names.  Then go through each dictionary in your array.  If your temp array has the screen name, skip it, otherwise take it and add the name to the temp array.

Comment: Hi,I made a tmp dictionary ,and userInfo insert this, and check screenName is already exist or not.Thanks to your Idea.